# creating new column based on whether the letter 'l' or 'L' is in the string of another column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, apply, feature-engineering

I am working with the Open Food Facts dataset which is very messy.
There is a column called quantity in which in information about the quantity of respective food. 
the entries look like:

```
365 g (314 ml)  
992 g  
2.46 kg  
0,33 litre  
15.87oz  
250 ml   
1 L    
33 cl
```

... and so on (very messy!!!)
I want to create a new column called `is_liquid`.
My idea is that if the quantity string contains an `l` or `L` the is_liquid field in this row should get a 1 and if not 0.
Here is what I've tried: 
I wrote this function:

```
def is_liquid(x):
    if x.str.contains('l'):  
        return 1  
    elif x.str.contains('L'):  
        return 1  
    else: return 0
```

(BTW: if something is measured in 'oz' is it liquid?)

And then tried to apply it

```
df['is_liquid'] = df['quantity'].apply(is_liquid)
```

But all I get is this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Could someone help me out?

Comment: "BTW: if something is measured in 'oz' is it liquid?"... yes, fluid ounces.

Comment: Try this `x.contains`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `case=False` for boolean mask and convert it to `integer`s by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['is_liquid']= df['liquids'].str.contains('L', case=False).astype(int)
print(df)
          liquids  is_liquid
0  365 g (314 ml)          1
1           992 g          0
2         2.46 kg          0
3      0,33 litre          1
4         15.87oz          0
5         250 ml           1
6             1 L          1
7           33 cl          1
```