# Extracting quantitative Information out of Strings

Tags: python, regex, pandas, feature-extraction, text-extraction

I am analyzing the Open Food Facts dataset.
The dataset is very messy and has a column called 'quantity' with entries like the following:

'100 g ',
'5 oz (142 g)',
'12 oz',
'200 g ',
'12 oz (340 g)',
'10 f oz (296ml) ',
'750 ml',
'1 l',
'250 ml',
'8 OZ',
'10.5 oz (750 g)',
'1 gallon (3.78 L) ',
'27 OZ (1 LB 11 OZ) 765g  ',
'75 cl',

As you can see the values and units of measurement are all over the place! Sometimes the quantity is given in two different measurements...
My goal is to create a new column 'quantity_in_g' in my pandas data frame where I extract the information out of the string and create an integer Value based on the number of grams from the 'quantity' column.
So if the quantity column has '200 g' I want the integer 200 and if it says '1 kg' I want the integer 1000. I would also like to convert the other units of measurements to grams. For '2 oz' I want the integer 56 and for 1 L I would like to get 1000.
Could someone help me to convert this column?
I would really appreciate it!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Haven't you asked this already?

Comment: No, My last question was how to extract the first integer from a string. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51811914/creating-new-column-based-on-whether-the-letter-l-or-l-is-in-the-string-of-a

Comment: Can you provide the desired output?

Comment: You could use the `re` (regex) module to extract the part in each line. I'm not familiar with regex, but I think it might be something like `r'.*(\d{0,4} g).*'`. Could anyone amend this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
raw_data_lst = ['100 g ','5 oz (142 g)','12 oz','200 g ','12 oz (340 g)','10 f oz (296ml)','750 ml','1 l','250 ml', '8 OZ',] 
# 10 f oz (296ml)  don't know what f is
# if more there is more data like this then gram_conv_dict.keys() loop over this instead of directly ... doing what i have done below

in_grams_colm = []
gram_conv_dict ={
    'g':1,
    'oz': 28.3495,
    'kg':1000,
    'l': 1000 # assuming 1 litre of water --> grams
    }
# ml --> g is tricky as density varies

def convert2num(string_num):
    try:
        return int(string_num)
    except ValueError:
        return float(string_num)

def get_in_grams(unit):
    try:
        return gram_conv_dict[unit.lower()]
    except:
        print('don\'t know how much grams is present in 1',unit+'.')

    return 1


for data in raw_data_lst:
    i = 0
    quantity_str =''
    quantity_num = 0
    while i < len(data):
        if  47 < ord(data[i]) < 58 or data[i] == '.':
            quantity_str+= data[i]
        else:
            # data[i] = '' most abbrv has at most length = 2 therefore data[i+1:i+3] or u can just send the whole data[i+1:]
            # gram_conv_dict[data[i+1:i+3].strip()] directly check if key exist
            break

        i+=1

    quantity_num = convert2num(quantity_str)*get_in_grams(data[i+1:i+3].strip()) # assuming each data has this format numberspace-- len 2 abbrv
    in_grams_colm.append(quantity_num) # if u want only integer int(quantity_num)

#print(in_grams_colm)

def nice_print():
    for _ in in_grams_colm:
        print('{:.2f}'.format(_))

nice_print()
'''
output

don't know how much grams is present in 1 f.
don't know how much grams is present in 1 ml.
don't know how much grams is present in 1 ml.
100.00
141.75
340.19
200.00
340.19
10.00
750.00
1000.00
250.00
226.80'''
```

Comment: You could use `enumerate` in the loop: `for I, data in enumerate(raw_data_list):`

Comment: @mooglinux yeah thanks :)

Comment: @mooglinux but I am using i for getting string(char) at index i from data not raw_data_list.